# FIll missing history records

Tags: sql-server

I have the following issue: I have two tables

```
Article
id     state
Guid    int
```

and

```
Article_history
id   state   datechange
Guid  int     datetime
```

First table store porduct information, second fills then product state changed. E.g.

```
Article
id     state
1       1

Article_history
id   state   datechange
1     1      2019-11-10
1     2      2020-01-15
```

I need to create a report for each article in several years period with one month step:

```
date         id   state
2019-11-01   1    1
2019-12-01   1    1 --There is my problem
2020-01-01   1    2
```

I create a query to `Article_history` table, but since my app create record only on change `Article state` not every month is presented in `Article_history`. In my example I actualy don't have record for 2019-12-01. I need to fill the time gaps for each product with the last known state.

I can't think about method to fill this gaps withot using cursor for each month in the given period but it takes to much time.
Please, give me advice.

UPD: Mock

```
 Create TABLE Article
(
    id int,
    state int
)

Create TABLE Article_history
(
    id int,
    datechange datetime,
    state int
)

Insert into Article (id, state)
VALUES (1,1)
,(2,1)
,(3,2)

INSERT into Article_history (id, datechange, state)
VALUES (1,'2019-11-10',1)
,(1,'2020-01-15',2);
```

My query:

```
 With theDates As
(
    Select DATEFROMPARTS(2019,11,1) as theDate
    Union All
    Select DateAdd(MONTH,1,theDate)
    From theDates
    Where DATEADD(MONTH,1,theDate)<=GETDATE()
)
Select 
    Convert(date,dt.theDate,104) as 'date'
    ,arth.id
    ,arth.state
From theDates as dt
left join Article_history as arth
on arth.datechange>=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, dt.theDate), 0) and arth.datechange<=EOMONTH(dt.theDate)
Option (Maxrecursion 0)
```

My Result:

```
date         id   state
2019-11-01   1    1
2020-01-01   1    2
```

I want to get

```
 date         id   state
 2019-11-01   1    1
 2019-12-01   1    1 
 2020-01-01   1    2
```

December is missing

To clarify my problem: record from `Article` can be not in `Article_history` at all, if so I want to put this record in every month with some defoult values.

Comment: Please, have a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Generate dates list in CTE (from the beginning of the history till its end or some needed date) using `FROM CTE LEFT JOIN SRC USING (DATE)` in recursive part, set the status to `COALESCE(SRC.DATE, CTE.DATE + 1 MONTH)`.

Comment: @Akina or make a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) for reusability

Comment: @Akina I don't know `using`keyword in MS SQL Server.